# How to get bitbucket webhook payload data in AWS Codebuild

Tags: bitbucket, aws-codebuild

Bitbucket sends a [payload in the webhook](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/event-payloads/) . [AWS Codebuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/bitbucket-webhook.html) allows to use some of the data passed within the payload but not all of them.

I am interested in the pull request ID and the pull request state (Open/Merged/Decline).
After looking at the documentation I did not find a way to identify which pull request triggered the AWS codebuild pipeline. If at least I got the pull request ID, I could use it to make an API call to Bitbucket to get the data I want. Does anyone know how to identify the pull request that started the AWS Codebuild pipeline?